# center align equation in ‎\documentclass[11pt,twoside,fleqn]{book}‎

Tags: align

I used the ‎`\documentclass[11pt,twoside,fleqn]{book}‎` for set formulas left, but I want to put formulas to center in some cases like original type without `[fleqn]`. What command do I use?
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
‎

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,fleqn]{book}‎‎
‎‎\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}‎
\begin{document}
‎\begin{align*}‎‎%This is in left 
‎y=f(x)
‎\end{align*}‎‎
\begin{align*}‎‎%This should be at the center
\centering
‎y=g(x)
‎\end{align*}‎
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the package nccmath and the environment ceqn to get centered equations.

```
\begin{ceqn}\begin{align*} ‎y=g(x) ‎\end{align*}‎\end{ceqn}
```