# Center Equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

Does anyone know how to center this equation?

```
\begin{align} 
r(P_i)=\sum\limits_{P_j \in B_{P_i}} \frac{r(P_j)}{|P_j|}
\label{eq:sum} 
\end{align}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is just a one line small equation (you do not need `\limits` here) so  `\begin{equation}r(P_i)=\sum_{P_j \in B_{P_i}} \frac{r(P_j)}{|P_j|}\end{equation}` will be centred unless you are using a document class that defaults to left alignment, but you have given no information in your question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! By default that should be centered, have you perhaps added `fleqn` to the options of the `documentclass` or `amsmath` package?

Answer (score 8):

`align`ed equations are typically centered by default, so without more information about your preamble it's hard to know for certain what the problem is.

That said, it's most likely that the problem arises from passing `fleqn` as an option to the document class. Removing this makes display math (including `align` environments) centered instead of left-aligned.

However, if you want to have some equations left-aligned and others centered, use the environment `ceqn` from the `nccmath` package, as so:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent This is left-aligned:
\begin{align}
   \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}\, dx = \arctan x + C.
\end{align}
This is centered:
\begin{ceqn}
\begin{align}
   \int \frac{1}{1+x^2}\, dx = \arctan x + C.
\end{align}
\end{ceqn}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:

[image]

Source: [this TeX.SX post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240531/55879).

Comment: the problem here is that single-line equations should be entered with `equation` (which is by default centered), not with `align`.  the spacing above and below the display is different in the two situations.