# Make the equation in the center

Tags: math-mode, align

I'm facing difficulties in compilation

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathrsfs}
      \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

    \begin{document}
     Let $\mathbf{T} = (T_1,\cdots,T_d)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H })^d$. The joint maximal numerical range  of $\mathbf{T}$ denoted $JtW_{\max}(\mathbf{T})$, is defined as
   \begin{align*}
     JtW_{\max}(\mathbf{T})
     & = \left\{(\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_d)\in \mathbb{C}^d;\;\exists\, 
     (x_n)_n\subset 
      \mathcal{H}\,;\;\;\|x_n\|=1,\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\langle T_k 
      x_n\mid x_n\rangle=\lambda_k,\\
     & \text{and}\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\|T_kx_n\|=\|T_k\|,\; 
       1\leq k \leq d\;\right\}.
    \end{align*}
      \end{document}
```

My goal is to get

[image]

Comment: A serious issue with the screenshot you posted is that the first line is wider than the textblock.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [center align equation in ‎\documentclass\[11pt,twoside,fleqn\]{book}‎](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240529/center-align-equation-in-documentclass11pt-twoside-fleqnbook)

Comment: @albert - It's not a duplicate: a main issue with the current query is that one of the lines is wider than the text block, making it impossible to center both lines.

Comment: you should also remove the `\displaystyle` (which do nothing there as align uses displaystyle anyway, but in other places would make an odd layout with half the expression on in textstyle and half in display  (it applies to the whole expression not just the `\lim`)

Comment: @mico thanks. OP: question should probably be posed a bit more  clearly, regarding error message, and header etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that it's not permissible to split the scope of `\left` and `\right` across two or more lines. Another issue is that the first line in the screenshot you posted is wider than the texblock.

I'd use a `multline*` environment instead of an `align*` environment, and I'd move `\lim_{n\to+\infty}\langle T_k x_n\mid x_n\rangle=\lambda_k` from the first line to the second.

Incidentally, both `\displaystyle` directives are redundant. And, you should be using `\dots` (or `\ldots`) rather than `\cdots` in two places.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,mathrsfs,mathtools,nccmath}
\newcommand\jtw{\mathit{Jt\!W}}
\newcommand\jtwmax{\jtw_{\!\!\max}}

\begin{document}
Let $\mathbf{T}=(T_1,\dots,T_d)\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})^d$. The joint maximal 
numerical range  of $\mathbf{T}$, denoted $\jtwmax(\mathbf{T})$, is defined as
\begin{multline*}
     \jtwmax(\mathbf{T})= \bigl\{
     (\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_d)\in \mathbb{C}^d; 
     \ \exists\, (x_n)_n\subset\mathcal{H};
     \ \|x_n\|=1, \\
     \lim_{n\to\infty}\langle T_k x_n\mid x_n\rangle=\lambda_k 
     \text{ and }
     \lim_{n\to\infty}\|T_kx_n\|=\|T_k\|,\ 1\leq k \leq d \bigr\}.
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. Just I hope to know what is the difference between `\left \right` and `\bigr`? Thanks.

Comment: @Schüler - `\left` and `\right` are for automatic sizing of round parentheses, square brackets, curly braces, and all other (mathematical) "fences". As noted earlier, `\left` and `\right` must not occur on different lines; that's why you can't use them for the two-line formula at hand. `\bigl\{` and `\big\}` increase the sizes of the curly braces by fixed amount. (Other fixed-amount sizing instructions are `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg`.) The formula doesn't require anything bigger than `\big` (pun intended).

Comment: I poste a similar question with 4 equations. Can I use `multine`?

Comment: `\begin{multline*}
W_{\max}^A(T)
=\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\,;\;\; \exists\,(b_n)_n\subset\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}\,;\;\;\|b_n\|_A=1,\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\langle T b_n\mid b_n\rangle_A=\lambda,\\
\text{and}\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\|Tb_n\|_A=\|T\|_A\;\}\\
=\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\,;\;\; \exists\,(b_n)_n\subset\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}\,;\;\;\|b_n\|_A=1,\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\langle PT b_n\mid b_n\rangle_A=\lambda,\\
\text{and}\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\| PTb_n\|_A=\|PT|_{\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}}\|_A\;\}=W_{\max}^{A_0}(T_0),
\end{multline*}`

Comment: However the `=` are not in the same signs. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Schüler - Please clarify what you mean by "Can I use `multline`?" Sure you can -- but what are you trying to achieve, in terms of formatting? Incidentally, if this were my document, I would *not* use a `multline` environment. Instead, I would use an `align*` environment.

Comment: @Schüler - I posted a [new answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/470472/5001) to the query you mentioned. It uses an `align*` environment, not a `multline*` environment, and it uses `\big` rather than `\Big` to size the curly braces.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I mean is `multline` should be the best solution of my problem?

Comment: @Schüler - In my view, `multline` is *not* a good solution for the 4-line math expression in your new query. This view is based on the fact that the full expression offers some very natural alignment points (the `=` symbols!) -- why not make use of these alignment points?

Comment: According to your previous answer, I thought that it is better to use `multline`, by  the way now the 3 answers are really good. Thank you again. Just a question in this answer why you prefer using `multline` instead of `align`?

Comment: @Schüler - In no way did I make a blanket statement of the type "it is better to use `multline`". Whether it's better to use `multline` or `align` very much depends on the math material at hand. For the answer shown above, I used `multline*` precisely because there were no natural alignment points across the two lines. But if one is dealing with a structure that does feature alignment points, it would be an error not to make use of them.

Comment: @Schüler - Sorry, but I don't readily give out my email address.

Comment: @Schüler - All I can do is restate that I value my privacy very much. Please respect that.