# Rearrange equation with multline

Tags: math-mode

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathrsfs}
      \usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

    \begin{document}
      We have
      \begin{align*}
      W_{\max}^A(T)
        &=\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\,;\;\; \exists\,(b_n)_n\subset\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}\,;\;\;\|b_n\|_A=1,\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\langle T b_n\mid b_n\rangle_A=\lambda,\\
      &\phantom{+++++++}\;\text{and}\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\|Tb_n\|_A=\|T\|_A\;\}\\
      &=\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\,;\;\; \exists\,(b_n)_n\subset\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}\,;\;\;\|b_n\|_A=1,\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\langle PT b_n\mid b_n\rangle_A=\lambda,\\
      &\phantom{+++++++}\;\text{and}\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\| PTb_n\|_A=\|PT|_{\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}}\|_A\;\}=W_{\max}^{A_0}(T_0),
      \end{align*}
      \end{document}
```

> It is possible to rearrange the above equations with `multline`?

Comment: What do you mean – ‘you can't use’?

Comment: When I use `= \Bigl\{
  \Bigr\}`,  it doen't work. I try also with `{multline*}`

Comment: In the code you posted?

Comment: Yes. When I add `&=\Bigl\{`

Comment: Why is there no `\Bigl` or `\Bigr` in the MWE to begin with? Just adding a random `\Bigl` in front of a `\{` works fine at my end. Additionally: What is the purpose of those `\displaystyle`'s? Here the code is already in displaystyle, so those macros only makes your code harder to understand.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it doesn't work." For sure, if I change both instances of `\{` to `\Bigl\{`, and both instances of `\}` to `\Bigr\}`, the code compiles just fine.

Comment: your code works fine with using `\Bigl\{` and `\Bigr\}`.

Comment: I mean the code does not work with   \left\{ and \right\}. I edit it.

Comment: You cannot break an equation that uses `\left...\right`, use the manual scalers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `multlined` environment from `mathtools`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}
We have
\begin{align*}
  W_{\max}^A(T)
  &=
    \begin{multlined}[t]
      \{
      \lambda\in \mathbb{C}\,;\;\;
      \exists\,(b_n)_n\subset\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}\,;\;\;
      \|b_n\|_A=1,\lim_{n\to+\infty}\langle T b_n\mid b_n\rangle_A=\lambda, \\
      \text{and }\lim_{n\to+\infty}\|Tb_n\|_A=\|T\|_A\;
      \}
    \end{multlined}
  \\
  &=
    \begin{multlined}[t]
      \{
      \lambda\in \mathbb{C}\,;\;\;
      \exists\,(b_n)_n\subset\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}\,;\;\;
      \|b_n\|_A=1,\lim_{n\to+\infty}\langle PT b_n\mid b_n\rangle_A=\lambda, \\
      \text{and }\lim_{n\to+\infty}\| PTb_n\|_A=\|PT|_{\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}}\|_A\;
      \}
    \end{multlined}
  \\
  &= W_{\max}^{A_0}(T_0),
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I really don't think that `multline` offers the best solution here. Instead, I would use an `align*` environment, and I would place `=W_{\max}^{A_0}(T_0)` on a new, separate line.

Incidentally, none of the four `\displaystyle` directives are needed. And, to cut back on the visual clutter, I would write `\infty`, not `+\infty`.

Finally, I don't thinks it's necessary to use `\Big`-sized curly braces; `\big`-sized ones will do just fine.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*} 
W_{\max}^A(T) 
  &=\bigl\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C};\;\; 
   \exists\,(b_n)_n\subset\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}\,;\;\;
   \norm{b_n}_A=1,
   \lim_{n\to\infty}\langle T b_n\mid b_n\rangle_A=\lambda,\\ 
  &\qquad\text{and }
   \lim_{n\to\infty}\norm{Tb_n}_A=\norm{T}_A\,\bigr\}\\ 
  &=\bigl\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C};\;\; 
   \exists\,(b_n)_n\subset\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}\,;\;\;
   \norm{b_n}_A=1,
   \lim_{n\to\infty}\langle PT b_n\mid b_n\rangle_A=\lambda,\\ 
  &\qquad\text{and }
   \lim_{n\to\infty}\norm{ PTb_n}_A=\norm{PT|_{\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}}}_A\,\bigr\}\\
  &=W_{\max}^{A_0}(T_0)\,.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This (simplified) code works for me. Note you don't have to load `amsmath` if you load `mathtools`– the latter does it for you.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsthm, mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

  We have
  \begin{align*}
  W_{\max}^A(T)
    &= \Bigl\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\,;
    \enspace\begin{aligned}[t] \exists\,(b_n)_n \subset \overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}\,;\enspace \|b_n\|_A & =1, \lim_{n\to+\infty} \langle T b_n\mid b_n\rangle_A = \lambda,\\
  \text{and }\lim_{n\to+\infty}\|Tb_n\|_A & = \|T\|_A\;\Bigr\}\end{aligned} \\
  &= \Bigl\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\,;\enspace\begin{aligned}[t] \exists\,(b_n)_n\subset\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}\,;\enspace \|b_n\|_A &= 1, \lim_{n\to+\infty} \langle PT b_n\mid b_n\rangle_A = \lambda,\\
  \text{and } \lim_{n\to+\infty}\| PTb_n\|_A & = \bigl\|PT|_{\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}}\bigr\|_A\;\Bigr\} = W_{\max}^{A_0}(T_0),\end{aligned}
  \end{align*}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you think that you cannot use as following `\begin{multline*}
     \jtwmax(\mathbf{T})= \bigl\{
     (\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_d)\in \mathbb{C}^d; 
     \ \exists\, (x_n)_n\subset\mathcal{H};
     \ \|x_n\|=1, \\
     \lim_{n\to\infty}\langle T_k x_n\mid x_n\rangle=\lambda_k 
     \text{ and }
     \lim_{n\to\infty}\|T_kx_n\|=\|T_k\|,\ 1\leq k \leq d \bigr\}.
\end{multline*}`

Comment: In my example we have for equations.

Comment: What is `\jtwmax` in the code of your comment?

Comment: Sorry `\newcommand\jtw{\mathit{Jt\!W}}
\newcommand\jtwmax{\jtw_{\!\!\max}}`

Comment: With these definitions, the code compiles fine.

Comment: `\begin{multline*}
W_{\max}^A(T)
=\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\,;\;\; \exists\,(b_n)_n\subset\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}\,;\;\;\|b_n\|_A=1,\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\langle T b_n\mid b_n\rangle_A=\lambda,\\
\text{and}\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\|Tb_n\|_A=\|T\|_A\;\}\\
=\{\lambda\in \mathbb{C}\,;\;\; \exists\,(b_n)_n\subset\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}\,;\;\;\|b_n\|_A=1,\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\langle PT b_n\mid b_n\rangle_A=\lambda,\\
\text{and}\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\to+\infty}\| PTb_n\|_A=\|PT|_{\overline{\mathcal{R}(A)}}\|_A\;\}=W_{\max}^{A_0}(T_0),
\end{multline*}`

Comment: However the `=` are not paralell. Please compile my last comment. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which `=` are not parallel? And what do you mean  with ‘parallel’ for = signs?

Comment: Yes I hope to obtain it as in `align`

Comment: In this case, use `align*` as I did in my answer! B.t.w., your `\displaystyle`s aren't needed.